# synchronized cache service implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am developing a java application where need to implement cache service to serve the requests. The requirement is like:

**1)**  1 or more threads come to fetch some data and if data is null is
         cache then only one thread goes to DB to load the data in cache.

**2)** Once done , all subsequent threads will be served from cache.

So for this the implementation is like:

```
public List<Tag> getCachedTags() throws Exception 
{
    // get data from cache
    List<Tag> tags = (List<Tag>) CacheUtil.get(Config.tagCache,Config.tagCacheKey);
    if(tags == null) // if data is null
    {
        // one thread will go to DB and others wait here
        synchronized(Config.tagCacheLock) 
        {
          // first thread get this null and go to db, subsequent threads returns from here.
           tags = (List<Tag>) CacheUtil.get(Config.tagCache,Config.tagCacheKey);
           if(tags == null)
           {
                tags = iTagService.getTags(null);
                CacheUtil.put(Config.tagCache, Config.tagCacheKey, tags);
                }
            }
        }
        return tags;
    }
```

Now is this the correct approach, and as I am making lock in a static String, then is not it will be a class level lock? please suggest me some better approach

Comment: *as I am making lock in a static String*.. Don't lock on `String`s !

Comment: can u please suggest any way, as there are several methods independent of each other. If i use a object for lock then I need a lock object for each of these.

Comment: Don't use a static field as a lock. Use a seperate `Lock`. Because in the former case, if you have other *independent* places in your code which lock on the class object, you will have unnecessary blocking / waiting

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel! Simply use [`ConcurrentMap.putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) in Java 7 - this will require some locking as you don't want to do the calculation if it's present . But if you are on Java 8 you can use [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) and do this in one line leaving all the locking to the `Map`. Or, even better, use a real cache...

Comment: That is what I am suspecting, Thanks , should I use a pool of lock  for independent methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to globally synchronize, just use custom object for this purpose:

```
private static final Object lock = new Object();
```

Do not use the `String` constant as they are interned, so the string constant with the same content declared in completely different part of your program will be the same `String` object. And in general avoid locking on the static fields. Better to instantiate your class and declare the lock as non-static. Currently you may use it as singleton (with some method like `Cache.getInstance()`), but later when you realize that you have to support several independent caches you will need less refactoring to achieve this.

In Java-8 preferred way to fetch object once is using the `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent` like this:

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public List<Tag> getCachedTags() throws Exception 
    List<Tag> tags = (List<Tag>)cache.computeIfAbsent(Config.tagCacheKey, 
      k -> iTagService.getTags(null));

    return tags;
}
```

This is simple and robust. In previous Java versions you may probably use `AtomicReference` to wrap the objects:

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicReference<Object>> cache = 
           new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public List<Tag> getCachedTags() throws Exception 
    AtomicReference<Object> ref = cache.get(key);
    if(ref == null) {
        ref = new AtomicReference<>();
        AtomicReference<Object> oldRef = cache.putIfAbsent(key, ref);
        if(oldRef != null) {
            ref = oldRef;
        }
        synchronized(ref) {
            if(ref.get() == null) {
                ref.set(iTagService.getTags(null));
            }
        }
    }
    return (List<Tag>)ref.get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as I am using Java 7 so implementing with the second approach, As as I am storing the data in ehcache so I can use the map for keys only.

Comment: @Enlightened if you are storing the data in EhCache why on earth are you messing around with locking?? And even if you insist on locking why on earth are you not locking on the `Cache` or at least the `CacheManager`?

Comment: @ Boris the Spider : Ha ha good one. It has nothing with any cache or cache manager. I think u did not get my requirement. Its like 1000 thread comes and all get null in cahce and all started loading data from DB, but what i want : 1000 comes --> all get null --> one goes to db to load cache, while others are waiting once loaded then other are served from cache.

Comment: @ Boris the Spider : And if I lock the cache manager then other requests which are fetching/setting completely different set of data independent of this method will also wait. This is why in this earth I am using locking

Comment: @Enlightened, please in future specify in the question that you are using EhCache and so on. Probably you're just misusing it and your *original* problem can be solved in easier way. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Enlightened if you want to ping me you need to stop adding spaces after the '@'... What's wrong with [`EhCache.getWithLoader`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.9/net/sf/ehcache/Ehcache.html)? It will do exactly what you want...

Comment: @BoristheSpider, that's what I suspected. I never used EhCache, but assumed that such simple problem should have a standard solution. The classic case of XY problem.

Comment: @Enlightened or the more general [`SelfPopulatingCache`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.6.9/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/blocking/SelfPopulatingCache.html) which decorates an ordinary cache and uses a [`CacheEntryFactory`](http://ehcache.org/apidocs/2.6.9/net/sf/ehcache/constructs/blocking/CacheEntryFactory.html) to load entries. This would be completely transparent to the application - but it requires that loading happens with no extra arguments.

Comment: @Boris the Spider : This time without space, Thanks for the suggestion. Never used EhCache.getWithLoader. Checking for this implementation.. any suggestion where I can get some references.

Comment: @Enlightened if you can use the `SelfPopulatingCache` then that's neater. Not sure about references beyond the JavaDoc.